# Pulling bootstrap into a new project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to dev in general so I'll do my best to ask the question the right way!

I built my first web app this month using RoR and Bootstrap for some styling.

Now, I want to use Bootstrap again in a new project that I'm building out purely on the front end (HTML, CSS, js).. I'm using espresso as my code editor.

How do I pull in all the bootstrap functionality into my new project? Do I need to move the files over to my new code folder? I tried the @import bootstrap in espresso and it didn't work :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if this solves your question could you please accept the answer .

Answer (score 0):

Just add a link tag in the head of your html page(s).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your/path/to/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: whoo hoo! thank you - is it better to pull the minified version in or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a link to your HTML page in the head section , linking the bootstrap library if you have downloaded it like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourpath/bootsrap.css">
```

You could also use a CDN if you do not want to download the files , like this one and just add the link to your head.

```
http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/
```

Similarly you can link other custom css files you have made .

Comment: thanks for this -- I'd +1 you but I'm not "reputable" enough on stackoverflow yet :]